# GCC 4.4.3 offsetof constant expression bug. How should I work around this?

Tags: android, c++, gcc

I have a struct that contains a static constant expression that uses the offset macro defined in stddef.h

```
struct SomeType {

    int m_member;
};

static const size_t memberOffset = offsetof(SomeType, m_member);
```

in GCC 4.4.3 (I'm using Androids NDK r7) this generates the following error:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/... -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -D__ARM_ARCH_5__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5T__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5E__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__  -Wno-psabi -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrict-aliasing -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300 - -I/Users/Byron/bin/android-ndk-r7/sources/cxx-stl/system/include -
 -Wa,--noexecstack   -O0 -g -w -D_ANDROID   -I/blah/bin/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include -c  
/MyFile.h:330: error: '->' cannot appear in a constant-expression
/MyFile.h:330: error: '&' cannot appear in a constant-expression
```

This seems like a compiler bug. Does anyone have a good workaround for this? I found references to a bug of this nature on GCC 3.4 but not later versions. hmmm

Comment: Maybe I'm losing my C chops, but don't you need a type on that?

    `static const int memberOffset = offsetof(SomeType, m_member);`

Comment: yeah sorry when pasting I stripped some stuff. I'll fix

Comment: I can confirm that `offsetof()` is required to expand to an integer constant expression; C++ inherits `offsetof()` from C, which explicitly states such a requirement.  The code in your question is incomplete; without a `#include` directive, the identifiers `size_t` and `offsetof` are not visible.  Try this: https://gist.github.com/1756545

Comment: I've added a C example, but the C++ example (c.cpp) is the one that's relevant to your question.

Comment: Looks okay on gcc-4.3.4 http://ideone.com/4Lu5H

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Standards

In the C++98 standard, there's some information in

> C.2.4.1 Macro `offsetof`(*type*, *memberdesignator*)             [diff.offsetof]
>
> The macro `offsetof`, defined in `<cstddef>`, accepts a restricted set of type arguments in this International
>   Standard. §18.1 describes the change.

(C.2.4.1 showed up with `offsetof` in the contents, so I went there first.)  And:

> §18.1 Types 18 Language support library
>
> ¶5 The macro `offsetof` accepts a restricted set of type arguments in this International Standard. *type*
>   shall be a POD structure or a POD union (clause 9). The result of applying the offsetof macro to a field that
>   is a static data member or a function member is undefined.

For comparison, the C99 standard says:

> ```
>  offsetof(type, member-designator)
> ```
>
> which expands to an integer constant expression that has type `size_t`, the value of
>   which is the offset in bytes, to the structure member (designated by *member-designator*),
>   from the beginning of its structure (designated by *type*). The *type* and *member designator*
>   shall be such that given
>
> ```
> static type t;
> ```
>
> then the expression `&(t.member-designator)` evaluates to an address constant. (If the
>   specified member is a bit-field, the behavior is undefined.)

---

#### Your code

Your code meets the requirements of both the C++ and C standards, it seems to me.

When I use G++ 4.1.2 and GCC 4.5.1 on RedHat (RHEL 5), this code compiles without complaint with the `-Wall -Wextra` options:

```
#include <cstddef>

struct SomeType {
    int m_member;
};

static const int memberOffset = offsetof(SomeType, m_member);
```

It also compiles without complaint with `#include <stddef.h>` and with the GCC compilers (if I use `struct SomeType` in the macro invocation).

I wonder - I got errors until I included `<cstddef>`...did you include that?  I also added the type `int` to the declaration, of course.

Assuming that you haven't made any bloopers in your code, it seems to me that you probably have found a bug in the `<cstddef>` (or `<stddef.h>`) header on your platform.  You should not be getting the error, and the Linux-based G++ appears to confirm that.

#### Workarounds?

You will need to review how `offsetof()` is defined in your system headers.  You will then probably redefine it in such a way as not to run into the problem.

You might be able to use something like this, assuming you identify your broken system somehow and execute `#define BROKEN_OFFSETOF_MACRO` (or add `-DBROKEN_OFFSETOF_MACRO` to the command line).

```
#include <cstddef>

#ifdef BROKEN_OFFSETOF_MACRO
#undef offsetof
#define offsetof(type, member)   ((size_t)((char *)&(*(type *)0).member - \
                                           (char *)&(*(type *)0)))
#endif /* BROKEN_OFFSETOF_MACRO */

struct SomeType {
    int m_member;
};

static const int memberOffset = offsetof(SomeType, m_member);
```

The `size_t` cast is present since the difference between two addresses is a `ptrdiff_t` and the `offset()` macro is defined to return `size_t`.  The macro is nothing other than ugly, but that's why it is normally hidden in a system header where you don't have to look at it in all its ghastliness.  But when all else fails, you must do whatever is necessary.

I know that once, circa 1990, I encountered a C compiler that would not allow 0 but it would allow 1024 instead.  The distributed `<stddef.h>` header, of course, used `0`, so I 'fixed' it by changing the 0 to 1024 (twice) for the duration (until I got a better compiler on a better machine).

Comment: this is an amazing answer! Thank you sir! I found a reference to cstdio and cstring which include the broken version of stddef. You da man!

Comment: For GCC 3.5 and above, it might be safer to define `offsetof` to `__builtin_offsetof`.

Answer (score 2):

`offsetof()` must be defined using pointer arithmetic.
GCC probably doesn't like that in constant expressions because in theory the pointers could change and so it is non-`const`.
Workaround might be make it a `static int` without `const`?

Comment: Yeah I considered that, however this is in cross-platform code and I'd had to ifdef around compiler bugs. Oh well.

Comment: Both `gcc` and `g++` expand `offsetof(SomeType, m_member)` to `__builtin_offsetof (struct SomeType, m_member)`.  Both C and C++ require `offsetof` to expand to an integer constant expression; any conforming compiler must do whatever is necessary to make that happen.